# Remove image next to header image on WellExpo theme

Tags: themes

We are using the WellExpo theme and when you view a specific post, next to the header image, there are 16 dots in a grid and an image for a missing image (see screenshot and the red box).

[image: How can we remove the part highlighted in red?]

We either want to remove these dots/image or know how to add an image.

We have tried (we think) changing every theme option, to no avail.

Can anybody tell us how we can access the relevant option/CSS (whatever) to manipulate this part of the post?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to hide it just add this to your css

```
.qodef-blog-holder article .qodef-post-type-id { display:none;}
```

Comment: Thank you so much - worked like a charm